# Divide page into two columns with fixed width

Tags: tables

I have following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\centering


\vfill

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ r l }

Author: & Author\\
E-Mail : & Veryyyyyyyyyyyyyyy loooooooooong\\

\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Results in the following:

[image]

As you can see by the drawn red line, the space between the columns is not centered.

What I want to do is have the page be split into two columns of the same width. Right now the space Between Column1 and Column2 is *not* centered.

I want something like this, where the columns are perfectly centered:

[image]

So I want both columns to have round about 50% of the page with. Column1 should be aligned right and Column2 should be aligned left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With use of the `tabularx` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
Author: & Author\\
E-Mail: & Veryyyyyyyyyyyyy loooooooong\\
    \end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Comment: works perfect. love you xoxo